# What would be the navigation option for us?

Tags: managed-metadata

I am working on a new sharepoint 2013 project and it's the first time as a team we have build a site with sharepoint.

We know there are two options for building navigation, managed and metadata. We are currently thinking that we should go down the metadata but to be honest, we are looking for some advice as to whether this is the correct thing to do.

We are likely to need to move pages around during the lifetime of the site. There will be multiple ways of access the information, it's not as clean cut as Pages X, Y and Z go under heading A and pages R, S and T go under heading B.

Is this the sort of thing metadata is suited for?

We would plan on having X number of panels on the homepage with maybe 4 links per panel, we want the freedom to display specific pages in each panel. 
Then within pages, we would want to display specific pages that are tagged in a specific way.

How would be filter and only display the information we want to show?

If you have any other questions please ask.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metadata (using Term Store) is most common way to store and maintain site navigation, including your case. I strongly suggest to use metadata navigation!

Comment: If we used the term store, would we need to build custom navigation or is there functionality within SharePoint to pull out the navigation that we want to display?

Comment: SharePoint provides UI to use metadata navigation. Go to "Site settings", under "Look and feel" group choose "Navigation" and select desired term set from Term Store. This [article](https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/sharepoint-2013-navigation-using-managed-metadata-term-store/) explains whole metadata navigation configuration process.